Qt memory leaks
I have code in QT creator and the following line creates memory leak:
action = new QAction(tr("New"), this);

action is in mainwindow.h.
According to Deleaker, it causes memory leak. How can this happen, if I assign action as a child to MainWindow? So it has to be destructed as MainWindow is desctructed...
Example:
mainwindow.h:
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QAction>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    void createAction();
    QAction *action;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

mainwindow.cpp:
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {}

void MainWindow::createAction() {
    action = new QAction(tr("New"), this);
}

This is a simplified example of my code, where happens memory leak

You're using new, so presumably there's a matching delete. A minimal reproducible example would be helpful.

@Chris wouldn't it be deleted anyway, because action is child of MainWindow?

Does the MainWindow destructor delete it?

wouldn't it be deleted anyway, because action is child of MainWindow? Yes. action = new QAction(tr("New"), this);  the this parameter at the end will solve the deletion problem using the QObject parent / child relationship. When the this object is destroyed all of its children will be destroyed.

where happens memory leak I expect the memory leak is a false positive.

Remember that diagnostic tools are not "the truth": they are instruments, and should always be used as such. Just like it is with any diagnostic approach, you need to know the underlying mechanism and be aware of the context, in order to understand how much a diagnosis is accurate.

Qt follows a special memory management scheme that doesn't require explicit call to delete on gui widgets. But that practice is against general C++ guidelines. Therefore static analyzers alert too many false positives on Qt. The responsibility is on the Qt though. The should have defined qt_ptr<T> smart pointer and make_qt initialization function instead. The way they handle memory management confuses the analyzer, and real leaks such as static initialization fiasco problems in the library escape debugging. A champion should start the safe qt open source project.

You can also consider reporting it to Deleaker as a bug.
